# Removing blank rows from csv files using python 3.3

Tags: python, csv, spaces

My current code produces the desired output but it inserts a space after every row. Could someone please advice how I might be able to tweak this code to omit blank spaces after every row? Thanks.

```
import csv

file1 = open ('Trial_1.csv', 'rt')
reader1 = csv.reader (file1)
file2 = open ('Trial_2.csv', 'rt')
reader2 = csv.reader (file2)
file3 = open ('Trial_3.csv', 'rt')
reader3 = csv.reader (file3)
readers  = (reader1, reader2, reader3)

WriteFile = open ('Trial_merged.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(WriteFile)

for reader in readers:
    next(reader, None)
    for col in reader:
        writer.writerow (col [0:3])


file1.close()
file2.close()
file3.close()
WriteFile.close()
```

Comment: Do your input files contain empty lines?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your input files contain empty lines. If that is the case, a quick fix would be to test for empty row before writing:

```
for reader in readers:
    next(reader, None)
    for col in reader:
        if col:
            writer.writerow (col [0:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I solved the problem. I had to inserted newline='' as my read and write parameter and it solved the problem. I'm not sure why that is but maybe it hints the program that if an empty space is encountered, a new line is required thus removing all empty rows.